# Get error when try to start workflow with PowerShell

Tags: workflow, powershell, designer-workflow, 2016, exception

We are using SharePoint 2016 on-premise. I setup a list workflow (Designer 2010 workflow) to send email to "assigned to" field in the item. Then I prepared a PowerShell script to loop through the list and start workflow on each item if the `status=Active`.

However, whenever I tried the same PowerShell error returned.

> Exception calling "StartWorkflow" with "3" argument(s): "Unable to
>   synchronously deliver start event via a manual-start workflow."

Here is part of my PowerShell script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $weburl -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment 
$site = Get-SPSite $siteurl
$listToloop = "Issues";
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;
$wfToStart= "sendemail"
$list = $web.Lists[$listToloop]; 

$manager=$site.WorkFlowManager
$association=$list.WorkFlowAssociations | where {$_.Name -eq $wfToStart}
$association.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$association.AllowManual = $true

foreach ($item in $list.Items) { 
$Lookup = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($Item["Status"])
    if ($Lookup.LookupValue -eq "Active") {
        $data=$association.AssociationData
        $wf=$manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$association,$data)
        Write-Output "$wftoStart started on " $item.Name | Out-File $outFile -Append
            }
        else {
        Write-Output $item.Name " - is completed " | Out-File $outFile -Append
        }
    }
```

If all the items status are not equal to "Active", no error. For each item with `status = "Active"`, the same error will throw repeatedly.

Comment: Is the user running this script has full control access on site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes, I am running the script within app server using farm admin

Comment: Try adding `$list.UpdateWorkflowAssociation($association)` after `$association.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true`.

Comment: Is it working for you? Or try adding `$list.WorkflowAssociations.Update($association)`.

Comment: After change, the script is throwing another error: `Exception calling "StartWorkflow" with "3" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Comment: and by some reason... after I commented the line $list.UpdateWorkflowAssociation($association) and run my script again.... the script is now working.....

Comment: Then what was the exact issue? I guess after updating workflow association, again you need to set the $association object with workflow association.

Comment: I tested setup a new list and a new list workflow. "Allow this workflow to be manually started" is checked. Exactly same error pattern occur (first see `Unable to synchronously deliver start` -> run `$list.WorkflowAssociations.Update($association)` get object reference not set -> run original code and working fine.

Comment: I changed my script to `$manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$association,$data,$true)` and it seems working always. However I am not sure what "$true" means in the 4th parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Start Updating your workflow association after setting:

```
$association.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true
$association.AllowManual = $true
```

Using:

```
$list.UpdateWorkflowAssociation($association)
```

Or

```
$list.WorkflowAssociations.Update($association)
```

**About StartWorkFlow() Method**:

The boolean parameter shows the property **isAutoStart**.

> This method comes with two overloads. The first overload takes an `SPListItem`
>   object, an `SPWorkflowAssociation` object, a string, and a Boolean as its arguments and creates a
>   workflow instance on the SharePoint list item or document represented by the `SPListItem` object
>   from the workflow association represented by the `SPWorkflowAssociation` object.
>
> **The method
>   starts the workflow instance if the Boolean parameter is true.** The method returns an
>   `SPWorkflow` object that represents the workflow instance.
>
> The second overload takes
>   an `SPListItem` object, an `SPWorkflowAssociation` object, and a string as its arguments and
>   creates a workflow instance on the SharePoint list item or document represented by the
>   `SPListItem` object from the workflow association represented by the `SPWorkflowAssociation`
>   object. This overload automatically starts the workflow instance.

Hope this helps you.

**Reference**:

1. [SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowmanager.startworkflow).
2. [Microsoft SharePoint 2007
   Workflow Programming](https://epdf.tips/download/professional-microsoft-sharepoint-2007-workflow-programming.html) - Page No. 339

Answer (score 0):

So, this answer makes no sense to me, but I did this:

$manager=$site.WorkFlowManager 
$association=$list.WorkFlowAssociations | where {$*.Name -eq $wfToStart} 

$association.AllowAsyncManualStart = $true 

$association.AllowManual = $true 

$list.UpdateWorkflowAssociation($association) 

$association=$list.WorkFlowAssociations | where {$*.Name -eq $wfToStart}

And it works consistently now. I guess after updating the association it is necessary to reload the association in memory? Hope it helps.